# Why is Redis used as an RDBMS cache when an RDBMS also has it's own cache?

Tags: redis, rdbms

Ok this maybe a silly question to you, but really please... i don't understand:

Why is Redis used as an RDBMS cache when an RDBMS also has it's own cache?

Both Redis and RDBMS is on the same server, or possibly even the same data center local area network.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common mistake since some RDBMS like Microsoft SQL Server can use in-memory tables (Memory Optimize Table).

So you can have the same cache as Redis, without paying more and having much more machines, resources and management to do so...

Just have a look on : [Introduction to Memory-Optimized Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/in-memory-oltp/introduction-to-memory-optimized-tables?view=sql-server-ver15)

Some other big RDBMS like Oracle have the same functionality but you have to pay for...

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you imply here. Are you saying that Redis is overkill?

Comment: There is no need to have a Redis database if your DBMS have the same features as REDIS ! In some RDBMS Like Microsoft SQL Server, you can use in-memory tables that deliver exactly the same service in addition to usual relational tables.

Comment: Thanks, then what the hell is redis for then?

Answer (score 0):

RDBMS only have limited optimizations with cache while Redis can be used to do customizable cache.